# Error running Grunt on Windows : Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I know there are lots of questions about this problem, but mine is a bit different.

I have nodejs installed on Windows , at c:\program files\nodejs

I installed all desired modules in the folder above, using these commands :

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin
npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin --save-dev
```

If i go inside my app folder and try to execute grunt, i get this error :

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt

Grunt will run only if i reinstall all modules INSIDE the folder of my app.

My question is : i have to install the modules inside EVERY app folder ? The same modules already installed on nodejs folder arent'enough ?

Thanks !

Comment: Installing node modules on a per project basis allows you to easily have multiple projects running different versions of the same dependencies. Storage is cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the modules should be installed inside project directory. If you want to install node module globally, you should use `--global` flag, eg `npm install --global grunt`. But installing grunt and grunt modules globally isn't good idea because of dependency management. You may get into trouble when update grunt or grunt modules installed globally.

Read grunt [Getting Started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) for more information.